# What's the problem in overriding the start() function in a threading.Thread object?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to have a main program that works like a console from where I can call other processes (infinite loops) and kill them selectively whenever certain commands are entered.

For that I created this class:

```
class RunInThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.kill_pill = threading.Event()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def start(self): # This is controversial.
        self.__init__(self.function)
        threading.Thread.start(self)    

    def stop(self):
        self.kill_pill.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.kill_pill.is_set():
            self.function()
```

The documentation for `thread.Thread` says that only the `__init__()` and `run()` methods should be overridden.
Is there any clear issue with my code? It works the way I intended but since it's going to be running for long periods of time I need to make sure I'm not creating any memory problems.

EDIT:

What about this solution?:

```
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    # threading.Thread class but can be stopped with the stop() method.
    def __init__(self, function):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.function = function
        self.kill_pill = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self.kill_pill.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.kill_pill.is_set():
            self.function()

class RunInThread():
    def __init__(self, function, prnt=False):
        self.function = function
        self.running = False
        self.prnt = prnt

    def start(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.thread = StoppableThread(self.function)
            self.thread.start()
            self.running = True
        else:
            if self.prnt:
                print('Thread already running.')

    def stop(self):
        self.thread.stop()
        self.running = False
```

Comment: As it stands, calling `self.__init__(...` inside a class method is not recomend, double work, could lead to unknown side effects and **useless** at all.

Comment: I'm doing that because for the threading.Thread class you can only start an object once, if you try to start it again it raises a RuntimeError. So instead of creating new Thread objects every time I want to start, I'm re-initializing it. A more elegant solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: `It works the way I intended` what are you intending to do? The code as written makes no sense. `Thread.__init__()` and `Thread.start()` are not supposed to be called more than once per thread instance. Maybe you're actually intending to implement a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)?

Comment: @Nacho ***"`.Thread` class you can only start an object once"***: Tricky to overcome this restriction this way. I could not recommend this.

Comment: You do not have to derive from a thread class in order to run your code. You don't have to derive from a file class either in order to read or write your data. Just write your code in a separate module or class and pass something callable to the constructor of `Thread`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt but the functions that I want to pass are infinite loops, for example checking an email account to see if there's something new.
So the idea is to have a main script waiting for input from the user, and based on the input of the user start and stop some functions that should work in parallel.

Comment: @LieRyan The idea is to have a main script waiting for input from the user, and based on the input of the user start and stop some functions that should work in parallel.
The user would for example type:
`-> start function1`
`-> start function 2`

both functions would start working in the background.

Then the user would write:
`-> kill function2`

function 2 would end and function1 would continue to work in the background.

Comment: Let me clarify: You don't have to derive from `threading.Thread` in order to run code in a separate thread. You can give a callable object as `target` parameter to the constructor of `threading.Thread` and then invoke the `start()` method to start a thread that calls the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find out what things that could break, I'd suggest looking into [the implementation of Thread](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py) class.

Among other things, `Thread.__init__()` initialises an Event() object to detect thread startup and shutdown, manages cleanup hooks/callbacks, some internal lock objects, and registers the thread to a list so you can introspect running threads. By calling `Thread.__init__()`, these variables gets reinitialised and screws up the internal mechanisms of many of these functionalities.

What could go wrong? I didn't test any of these, but from skimming through threading.py, these are likely some of the things that I expect could go wrong:

- your python process now will be running a OS threads that doesn't show up in enumerate_thread()
- multiple OS thread will now return the same Thread object when it calls current_thread(), which will likely also break threadlocal and anything that depends on threadlocal
- Thread.join() depends on some internal locks, which likely would now become thread unsafe to call
- Unhandled reception can go to the wrong exception hook handler
- register_at_fork and shutdown handler likely will get confused

In other words, don't try to be sneaky. Create a new Thread object for each thread you want to start.

There's a good reason that the Thread class spent efforts trying to prevent you from accidentally calling start() twice. Don't try to subvert this.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thanks!